# How to delete Safari.app on Ventura?

Tags: safari, permission, macos, ventura

I want to delete Safari. It doesn't support an internet filter extension that exists for Chrome and Firefox and I don't want it to be accessible at all. Apple has historically made it very difficult to uninstall Safari, requiring disabling SIP and removing it through the terminal. With the macOS Ventura update, unfortunately, Safari.app is now in a folder labeled 'Cryptexes' and is read-only, and I cannot delete it. How can I gain read-write permissions to delete Safari.app? The `sudo mount -uw` won't give any errors, but the Safari.app remains read-only. How can I delete it?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I suspect the answer will be "you can't"

Comment: As @Ezekiel says, or go back to Monterey. What is the problem with leaving Safari alone? Safari is part of macOS; if you don't like it that much, you could move to Windows!

Comment: Please describe this "Cryptexes" folder more. Safari should be in /Applications. It is 15 Mb in size. If you don't want to use it, just leave it alone. It's not going to interfere with your 'filter extension' at all.

Comment: @benwiggy Safari is updatable separately from the OS, so it uses a macOS Ventura feature ("Cryptexes") that allows it to be updated while protected from manipulation. In past Versions, it was just an application in the application folder but that is no longer the case

Comment: @Ezekiel I knew it was now separate, but I woudl have thought Apple would have used a slightly less .... cryptic .. name.

Comment: Well, it's not really user facing. Safari still appears in the Applications folder